# Spring Security - Get login user within Controllers - Good manners

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing my very first application with Spring (4.0.2), Spring @MVC (4.0.2) and Spring Security (3.2.5). I am now able to successfully log in by using Spring Security but now a "Good practices" question has come to my mind:

Currently I hace implemented my own version of `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` in order to save the details fetched from the DB.

**Which is the best way (cleaner) to get the `UserDetails`?**

So far I am using these two alternatives:

1. Using the next code line in the method

   ```java
   Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   ```
2. Adding the parameter `Authentication auth` and the next line inside the method

   ```java
   User user = ((CurrentUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal()).getCurrentUser();
   ```

My impression is that I am dirtying the code. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 5):

On every project I have worked on, we have always implemented `SecurityUtils` class with at least the following methods:

```
/**
 * Get the active authentication object.
 * @param strict Whether to throw an exception if no authentication object is found.
 * @return Authentication object. Can be null only in non-strict mode.
 */
public static Authentication getAuthentication(boolean strict) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (strict && authentication == null) {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Missing authentication object.");
    }
    return authentication;
}

/**
 * Get active person principal.
 * @return Active person principal user. Never null.
 * @throws AccessDeniedException in case there is no active person principal.
 */
public static PersonPrincipal getActivePersonPrincipal() {
    Object principal = getAuthentication(true).getPrincipal();
    if (!(principal instanceof PersonPrincipal)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Invalid principal '" + principal + "'.");
    }
    return (PersonPrincipal) principal;
}
```

This class usually sits in `{projectPackage}.core.security` package. Whenever any code needs access to the current user, it calls this class.

Also we never let controller layer tell service layer anything about authentication. Service layer (or even Hibernate event listeners) are always asking `SecurityUtils` about the current authentication.

Comment: Thanks for this approach! I like it! On the other hand, is it really a good idea to "mix" `SecurityContext` layer with Service or even Repository/DAO? Aren't you forcing those layers to tightly depend on SpringSecurity. For instance, for Unit Tests.

Comment: Yes, you are tying those to security context by this approach. In unit tests we usually set up fake authentication.

Comment: Is it good practice to "never let controller layer tell service layer anything about authentication"? Firstly i read your post and then this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal. Don't know what the way is better.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security is able to put the `Authentification` in the request where it can be retrieved with `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`. And in Spring MVC, the controller can have access to the principal simply by passing it as a parameter.

So, IMHO one of the simpler way to access the login user from a controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String method(Principal principal, ...) {
    Authentication auth = (Authentication) principal;
    ...
}
```

Edit (per comment) :

If you do not want to repeat the code on each controller method, you can :

- use a `@ModelAttribute` method to populate the model with the login user in a single place (mainly if you use it in views)
- put it in a request scoped bean and directly inject it in controllers through an AOP scoped proxy.

Comment: Yep! That's one of the techniques I'm using but I think I am populating the code. In some controllers I add this argument in almost all methods... That smells.